# How to access 'this' from within an addEventListener?

Tags: javascript

I'm wanting to access `this` from within an `addEventListener`.

With my example below I want to output `this.settings.car` when a div is clicked.

I could write `var that = this` within the `this.init = function() { //here }` and access it using `that.settings.car`, however if I run multiple instances of this code then `that` will always reference the last instance.

Else I could rewrite the addEventListener to be:

```
this.settings.wrap.addEventListener('click', function (e) => {
     console.log(this.settings.car)
})
```

and that'll work, however this will lead to me writing lots of duplicate code instead of 1 function.

I've been scratching my head at this for a while now. How can I access this from within the `this.test` function?

```js
var gauge = (function() {
  return function() {
    
    this.settings = {
      car: undefined,
    }
    
    this.init = function(e) {
      this.settings.wrap = document.querySelector(e.wrapper)
      this.settings.car = this.settings.wrap.innerText     
      
      this.settings.wrap.addEventListener('click', this.test)      
    }   
    
    this.test = function(e) {

      console.log('clicked')
      console.log(this.settings.car)
      
    }
    
  }
}())


// init
let boy = new gauge()
boy.init({
  wrapper: '.boy'
})

let girl = new gauge()
girl.init({
  wrapper: '.girl'
})
```

```css
div {display:block;background:grey;margin:20px;height:200px;width:200px;color:white;text-align:center;line-height:200px;}
```

```html
<div class="boy">ford</div>
<div class="girl">ferrari</div>
```

Here's a jsbin of the issue: https://jsbin.com/xayuheyime/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrow function seems fine here. Another way is how you suggested, use **var that = this**  before your **this.init** function, and use **that** on your event handler call.

```
var gauge = (function() {
  return function() {
    
    this.settings = {
      car: undefined,
    }
    
    this.init = (e) => {
      this.settings.wrap = document.querySelector(e.wrapper)
      this.settings.car = this.settings.wrap.innerText
      
      this.settings.wrap.addEventListener('click', this.test)
    }   
    
    this.test = () => {
      console.log('clicked')
      console.log(this.settings.car)
    }
    
  }
}())


// init
let boy = new gauge()
boy.init({
  wrapper: '.boy'
})

let girl = new gauge()
girl.init({
  wrapper: '.girl'
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) to set the `this` value.

```
this.settings.wrap.addEventListener('click', this.test.bind(this))
```

```js
var gauge = (function() {
  return function() {
    
    this.settings = {
      car: undefined,
    }
    
    this.init = function(e) {
      this.settings.wrap = document.querySelector(e.wrapper)
      this.settings.car = this.settings.wrap.innerText     
      
      this.settings.wrap.addEventListener('click', this.test.bind(this))      
    }   
    
    this.test = function(e) {

      console.log('clicked')
      console.log(this.settings.car)
      
    }
    
  }
}())


// init
let boy = new gauge()
boy.init({
  wrapper: '.boy'
})

let girl = new gauge()
girl.init({
  wrapper: '.girl'
})
```

```css
div.boy, div.girl {display:block;background:grey;margin:20px;height:200px;width:200px;color:white;text-align:center;line-height:200px;}
```

```html
<div class="boy">ford</div>
<div class="girl">ferrari</div>
```